# How can I remove text from a string in PowerAutomate?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have text that populates when I do a pull from a SharePoint list in PowerAutomate. The text populates as:

```
{"@data.type":"#Text.SharePoint.Text":1,"Value":"Normal"}
```

How can I clean this in PowerAutomate so that just the portion that says Normal (without quotations) appears?

Comment: You’re not “cleaning” in it, you’re interrogating the data, there’s a big difference.

Comment: Also, your JSON is ill formed.  Can you fix that please?

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters pointed out before, the sample text is not a well-formed JSON. The solution would be very straightforward if the text was a JSON object - you could simply use the `Parse JSON` data operation. Maybe it makes sense to format the output from SharePoint properly to clean the data.

With the given string, you can use `Compose` actions to split the text into an array and remove extra characters from an array element.

[image]

The first Compose expression is `split(variables('InputString'), ':')`
It returns an array of text parts.
This is the output which will be fed to the next action.

```
[
  "{\"@data.type\"",
  "\"#Text.SharePoint.Text\"",
  "1,\"Value\"",
  "\"Normal\"}"
]
```

Second Compose removes curly brackets and quotation marks:

```
replace(replace(last(outputs('Compose')), '"', ''), '}', '')
```

As a side note, applying a regular expression to the input text would be a neater way to extract a piece of text, but Power Automate does not have native support of regular expressions, and I'm not considering third-party connectors.

Answer (score 0):

Use ParseJson flow and paste the json in schema section.
Then use "Value" column to get the value without quotes.